# Unexpected behaviour from multiple bitwise shift operators in an expression

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, expression, bit-shift

I noticed that a program that I was writing was not working correctly so I wrote a simple test to check if the problem was the binary shifting.
The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    BYTE byte = 0b10010000; //This is 2^7 + 2^4 = 144
    cout << "This is the binary number 10010000: " << endl << "Numerical value: " << (unsigned short int) byte << endl << "Binary string: " << bitset<8>(byte) << endl;

    byte = byte << 1;
    cout << "Shifted left by 1 with << 1:" << endl << "Numerical value: " << (unsigned short int) byte << endl << "Binary string: " << bitset<8>(byte) << endl;

    byte = byte >> 5;
    cout << "Shifted right by 5 with >> 5: " << endl << "Numerical value: " << (unsigned short int) byte << endl << "Binary string: " << bitset<8>(byte) << endl;

    byte = 0b10010000;
    byte = (byte << 1) >> 5; //Expect to store 00000001 inside byte
    cout << "But what happens if I do it all in one line? " << endl << "Numerical value: " << (unsigned short int) byte << endl << "Binary string: " << bitset<8>(byte) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output produced

By running it, the following output is produced:

This is the binary number 10010000:
Numerical value: 144
Binary string: 10010000
Shifted left by 1 with << 1:
Numerical value: 32
Binary string: 00100000
Shifted right by 5 with >> 5:
Numerical value: 1
Binary string: 00000001
But what happens if I do it all in one line?
Numerical value: 9
Binary string: 00001001

#### What I was expecting

I expected the last messages printed by `cout` would be:

But what happens if I do it all in one line?
*Numerical value: 1

Binary string: 00000001*

But surprisingly enough, this wasn't the case.
Can someone explain to me why does this happen? I tried checking microsoft documentation but found nothing.

*Additional info*:
The type BYTE is defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Comment: What is the output you get? What is the output you expect? Please [edit] your question to tell us. And please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: And what compiler did you use : https://godbolt.org/z/nTEhYhjKf (clang seems to be doing the right thing). And what is BYTE, signed or unsigned?

Comment: However, as a hint, please read about [*integer promotion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

Comment: If you print `byte << 1` directly, you will notice that it is not 32 but 288, and `288 >> 5` is 9. (Now take that hint and read about integer promotions.)

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude Thanks, that link was exactly the answer I needed. By the way, I edited the question as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing the effects of integer promotion.

The operation `byte << 1` does not produce an `unsigned char`, despite `byte` being of that type. The rationale is that hardware usually cannot perform a number of operations on small types (below a machine word) so C++ inherited from C the concept of promoting data types in operations to larger types.

So since the result is not 8 bits but, probably, 32 bits, the most significant bit is not shifted out but preserved. After you shift the 32 bit value back and implicitly convert it back to an `unsigned char` the bit is back in your output.